Vertical split happens randomly
I understand this is part of Tiling Window feature but the selection remains persistent even when I don't want to. Do you know of any shortcuts to manage these tiling window selections ?


23.04 has reached EOL https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/

Update your tag - you probably ment 24.4 instead of 23.04, otherwise your post is going to be closed. If you effectively run 23.04, then upgrade. What do you mean with "when you don't want it"? Instead describe what you do and when you expect the highlight to go away. Otherwise we cannot test whether the behavior is anomalous. Include information on your graphics card. For now, a workaround will be to disable the ability to drag to the edges to tile. You still can use Super+Left/Right for tiling.
